# Javascript Date format "dd-MMM-yyyy" not working in IE

Tags: javascript, angular, date, internet-explorer

I am having the date format `dd-MMM-yyyy` while getting data from server side.
I am doing some validation with it like

```
 if (new Date("02-MAY-2018").toDateString() == new Date(this.dob).toDateString()) {
   alert("No error");
 }
 else {
   alert("error");
 }
```

Here `new Date("02-MAY-2018").toDateString()` this conversion is working on chrome, but not in IE

Comment: I would say that: `The string should be in a format recognized by the Date.parse() method (IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps and also a version of ISO8601).` --and -- `parsing of date strings with the Date constructor is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies. Support for RFC 2822 format strings is by convention only. Support for ISO 8601 formats differs in that date-only strings (e.g. "1970-01-01") are treated as UTC, not local.` - MDN

Comment: note: doesn't work in Firefox either

Answer (score 2):

If you know the pattern of date string that you are getting will not change then you can write your own parser. This should work across all the browsers.

```js
const date = "02-MAY-2018";

const parseDate = dateStr => {
  const parts = dateStr.split('-');
  const months = ['january', 'february', 'march', 'april', 'may', 'june', 'july', 'august', 'september', 'october', 'november', 'december'];
  const day = Number(parts[0]);
  const month = Number(months.indexOf(parts[1].toLowerCase()));
  const year = Number(parts[2]);

  return new Date(year, month, day);
}

console.log(parseDate(date).toDateString());
```

It is a little bit verbose but it gets the job done.

And then you can simply change your code like this:

```
if (parseDate("02-MAY-2018").toDateString() == new Date(this.dob).toDateString()) {
  alert("No error");
} else {
  alert("error");
}
```

Note that you might need to change the right side of the comparison - `new Date(this.dob)` to `parseDate(this.dob)` depending on the structure of `this.dob`

Comment: I modified your code and that is working 
`parseDate(dateStr) {
  const parts = dateStr.split('-');
  const months = ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC'];
  const day = parts[0];
  const month = months.indexOf(parts[1]);
  
  const year = parts[2];

  const date = new Date(year, month, day);
  return date;
}`

Answer (score -2):

1) I think the format, you are talking about is `dd-MM-yyyy`, not `dd-MMM-yyyy`, right?

2) If yes, then you should understand that Date object, parses it like `MM-dd-yyyy`.

So you should either change the format, either, replace days with months in your received string.

Comment: Actually I 'm using the format `02-MAY-2018` as mentioned above

Comment: Try using .parse function: Date.parse('02-MAY-2018')

Comment: `new Date("02-05-2018").toDateString()` gives Invalid date error in IE, not in Chrome